# C++ template class error: function returning a function

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I want to make a simple logger which automatically runs a function and returns its value.
The class is defined as:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Logger3
{

    Logger3(function<R(Args...)> func,
            const string& name):
        func{func},
        name{name}
    {}
    R operator() (Args ...args)
    {
        cout << "Entering " << name << endl;
        R result = func(args...);
        cout << "Exiting " << name << endl;
        return result;
    }
    function<R(Args...)> func;
    string name;
};
```

I want to pass the following simple `add` function to the logger:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    cout<<"Add two value"<<endl;

    return a+b;
}
```

By calling it this way:

```
auto caller = Logger3<int(int,int)>(add,"test");
```

However, it generates the following errors:

```
error: function returning a function
  133 |     Logger3(function<R(Args...)> func,
      |     ^~~~~~~
decorator.h:138:7: error: function returning a function
  138 |     R operator() (Args ...args)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
decorator.h:145:26: error: function returning a function
  145 |     function<R(Args...)> func;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There are 3 issues in your code:**

1. The `Logger3` class template requires `R` to be the **return value** of the function (and `Args` it's **arguments**).
   (`R` is not a function type as implied by your attempt to instantiate `Logger3`).
   Therefore instantiating the `Logger3` in your case of a function that gets 2 `int`s and returns an `int` should be:

```
auto caller = Logger3<int, int, int>(add, "test");
```

2. Your `Logger3` **constructor** should be **public** in order to invoke it from outside the class.
3. For **efficiency** reasons, you should use [**`std::forward`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to forward the arguments from `operator()` to your function. This will avoid copy of the arguments (more significant in cases where their types are more complex than `int`s).
   **Note** that in order for `std::forward` to work as expected, `operator()` has to be itself a variadic template using **forwarding references** (see below).

**Complete fixed version:**

```cpp
#include <string>     // std::string
#include <functional> // std::function
#include <utility>    // std::forward, std::declval
#include <iostream>   // std::cout

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Logger3
{
public:
    Logger3(std::function<R(Args...)> func,
        const std::string& name) :
        func{ func },
        name{ name }
    {}

    // Template with forwarding references to avoid copies
    // 'typename' arg is for SFINAE, and only enables if a 
    // function accepting 'Args...' can evaluate with 'UArgs...'
    template <typename...UArgs,
              typename = decltype(std::declval<R(*)(Args...)>()(std::declval<UArgs>()...))>
    R operator() (UArgs&&...args)
    {
        std::cout << "Entering " << name << std::endl;
        R result = func(std::forward<UArgs>(args)...);
        std::cout << "Exiting " << name << std::endl;
        return result;
    }
private:
    std::function<R(Args...)> func;
    std::string name;
};

int add(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << "Add two value" << std::endl;
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    auto caller = Logger3<int, int, int>(add, "test");
    auto res = caller(3, 4);
    std::cout << "result: " << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Entering test
Add two value
Exiting test
result: 7
```

Demo: [Godbolt](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/7W4sPG6ev).

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: `Args` in `operator()` is from the primary class template and not from a function template. This means that `Args...` is _not_ a forwarding reference. If the function is defined to have arguments taken by-value, then there will always be a copy of the argument when calling `operator()`. You can avoid copies even if `Args...` are by value if `operator()` was itself a variadic template using forwarding references: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/6GfGjbnYP.

Comment: @Human-Compiler thanks. I fixed my answer regarding the forwarding reference. I kept the way the main template args for Logger3 were defined in my answer so I did not need the partial specialization. The other answer in this post offers the solution with the partial specialization.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use template class partial specialization to get the type of `R`.

```
template <typename F>
class Logger3;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Logger3<R(Args...)>
{
  // implementation details
};
```

which makes `int` match the template parameter `R` of the partial specialization when you explicitly specify `Logger3<int(int,int)>`.